# JSON.stringify() object not working in ajax call in Codeigniter

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

```
var dataString = JSON.stringify(formDara);
    console.log(dataString);
$.ajax({
    url: urL,
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    data: dataString,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Here, `formData` is an Object.
console.log(dataString) OUTPUT:

```
{"library_fee":"100","lab_fee":"200","tution_fee":"300","admission_fee":"400"}
```

But my controller got no value.
Codeigniter controller ACTION method:

```
public function set_fees_structure($id) {
    $data = array();
    $data["admission_fee"] = $this->input->post("admission_fee", TRUE);
    $data["tution_fee"] = $this->input->post("tution_fee", TRUE);
    $data["library_fee"] = $this->input->post("library_fee", TRUE);
    $data["lab_fee"] = $this->input->post("lab_fee", TRUE);
    echo 'I m set fees structures ' . $id;
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($data);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Add your action method also. You need  add to ajax method `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'`

Comment: I already tried. but not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21004315/passing-form-data-to-controller-using-ajax-and-jquery-with-codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

Try this @Ikram Hasib

Method 1

```js
    var jsonFile = {
      "coord": {
        "lon": -88.64,
        "lat": 35.44
      },
      "weather": [{
        "id": 701,
        "main": "Mist",
        "description": "mist",
        "icon": "50n"
      }]
    }
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: JSON.stringify({
        jsonFile
      }),
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: "application/json",
      Accept: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
```

Method 2

```js
 var jsonFile = {
   "coord": {
     "lon": -88.64,
     "lat": 35.44
   },
   "weather": [{
     "id": 701,
     "main": "Mist",
     "description": "mist",
     "icon": "50n"
   }]
 }

 $.post(url, JSON.stringify({
     jsonFile
   }))
   .done(function(data) {
     console.log(data);
   });
```

Comment: When i use dataType: "json", then not work ajax. when use that still not working. for your information, formDara is an Object

Comment: @IkramHasib I have added another way too of doing it and updated my old code.

Comment: please check that data 
{"library_fee":"100","lab_fee":"200","tution_fee":"300","admission_fee":"400"}